# Accessing DOM element siblings using angular js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I have a link function in an directive where i have a toggle functionality to edit the currently active DOM element's css content . How do i access the parent or child class of that DOM element .

A part of the directive :

```
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var title = angular.element(element.children()[0]),
            opened = true;

        title.bind('click', toggle);

        function toggle() {
            opened = !opened;
                element.removeClass(opened ? 'closed' : 'opened');                  
                element.addClass(opened ? 'opened' : 'closed');
            element.siblings().removeclass('opened').addclass('closed');  // What to do here  

        }
```

Comment: Better would be to post your relevant code

Comment: meaning Currentlty active DOM elements siblings ...

Comment: You can edit your question, you know...

Comment: @asgoth : [scope.$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply) didnt work ...it took more time to load the file in the browser after i changed and angular binding to the front end failed

Answer (score 1):

I would change your link function to this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var title = angular.element(element.children()[0]),
        opened = true;

    title.bind('click', toggle);

    function toggle() {
        opened = !opened;
        element.parent().children().addClass("closed");
        element.parent().children().removeClass("opened");
        element.toggleClass("opened", opened);
        element.toggleClass("closed", !opened); //might be redundantdepending on the rest of your code

    }
}
```

I think you're doing it in the wrong order, if you first remove/add all the classes you need and then modify the element you'll get the result you're after. Simply select the elements parent, and then get all it's parent children. .children() selects only the direct descendents of the parent, while the .find() method which is similar would traverse down the hierarchy. The redundant code might not be necessary depending on if there are other ways to close the element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MatthewBerg ...I ll look through that :)

Comment: What do i do if i already have a "closed" class for one of the children elements ... ie if the function toggle already took place for that element , then a closed class would already exist ... 
>      element.parent().children().addClass("closed");
then wouldnt i be adding the "closed" class again

Comment: No, it will just leave 1 closed class. If an element already has a class and you try to add it again it won't duplicate it.